# Удалить слово из текстового поля input по клику мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется форма отправки запроса:

```
<form name="search" action="/search" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText">
<button id="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Слова в поле input вводятся пользователем вручную и разделяются пробелами.

Вопрос: как (и возможно ли) с помощью JS/JQuery удалить любое слово из текстового поля по клику мыши на нем?

Например: текст в input - "шкаф купе бежевый". Пользователь кликает на слово "купе" и оно удаляется, остается в текстовом поле "шкаф бежевый".

Может быть следует использовать какие-то другие конструкции?

Comment: удалить весь текст который в input или только то слово на которое кликнули?

Comment: @gfd2 написано же, любое слово при клике по нему.

Comment: простой клик вы имеете в виду, либо двойной с автоматическим выделением слова?

Comment: желательно одиночный клик.

Comment: Вот так вот решишь ошибку в слове поправить, тыкнешь по ошибке и слово удалиться.. Не практично, имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegExp для `\S+` даст нам и слова, и индексы:

```js
searchText.onclick = (e) => {
  let input = e.target;
  let pos   = input.selectionStart;
  let words = Array.from(input.value.matchAll(/\S+/g));

  let index = words.findIndex(v => pos > v.index && pos < v.index + v[0].length);

  if (index > -1) {
    let start = words[index].index;
    let count = words[index][0].length;

    let letters = [...input.value];
    letters.splice(start, count + 1);

    input.value = letters.join('').trimRight();
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="search" action="/search" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" value="hello crazy man crazy hello">
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Дополнение**
Чтобы работало по двойному щелчку:

```js
searchText.ondblclick = (e) => {
  ...
```

По нажатию правой кнопки:

```js
searchText.oncontextmenu = (e) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: Это замечательное ёмкое решение, но оно не позволяет удалять однобуквенные слова (например, а, я, и)

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Спасибо за комментарий и замечание. Чтобы удалять однобуквенные слова, нужно изменить условие `pos > v.index` на `pos >= v.index`. Сложно как-то одну букву словом называть...

Comment: как изменить код, чтобы он работал по нажатию правой кнопки мыши?

Comment: или по двойному щелчку левой.

Comment: @Ruport Дополнил свой ответ, проверьте

Comment: благодарю. Если у меня два текстовых поля, то код обязательно дублировать и для второго? или возможно как-то через запятую name-ы полей перечислить или массивом?

Comment: Не надо дублировать. Оформите код в отдельную функцию и указывайте в качестве обработчика событий для нужных текстовых полей.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте совместимость: [`selectionStart`](https://caniuse.com/?search=selectionStart).

```js
var searchText;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    searchText = document.getElementById("searchText");
    searchText.onpointerup = function() {
        let text = searchText.value;
        let cursorPos = searchText.selectionStart;
        searchText.value = cutString(text, cursorPos, " ");
    }
}

function cutString(string, position, delimiter) {
    if (position == string.length) return string;
    let hasNext = true, hasPrev = true;
    let prevSpacePos = string.lastIndexOf(delimiter, position);
    if (prevSpacePos == -1) {
        hasPrev = false;
        prevSpacePos = 0;
    }
    let nextSpacePos = string.indexOf(delimiter, position);
    if (nextSpacePos == -1) {
        hasNext = false;
        nextSpacePos = string.length;
    }
    return string.slice(0, hasNext? hasPrev? prevSpacePos+1 : prevSpacePos : prevSpacePos) + string.slice(hasNext? nextSpacePos+1 : nextSpacePos);
}
```

```html
<form name="search" action="/search" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Субмит</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать таким образом:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#t1');

input.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const target = e.target;
  const clickPosition = target.selectionStart;
  const value = target.value;
  const splitSymbol = ' ';
  let wordStartPosirion = 0;
  let wordEndPosition = value.length;


  for (let i = clickPosition; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      wordStartPosirion = 0;
      break;
    } else if (value[i] === splitSymbol) {
      wordStartPosirion = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (let i = clickPosition; i < value.length; ++i) {
    if (i === value.length - 1) {
      wordEndPosition = value.length;
      break;
    } else if (value[i] === splitSymbol) {
      wordEndPosition = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  const word = value.slice(wordStartPosirion, wordEndPosition);
  
  e.target.value = value.replaceAll(word, (matchedWord, i) => {
    if (i === wordStartPosirion) return '';
    
    return matchedWord;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t1" value="abcd sdsds abcd">
```